# Does .class file of subclass contain byte code of base class

Tags: java, android

I have a confusion. Let I have a Base class -

```
class Base{
  // members of parent class
}
```

Now I have a subclass Child1 as -

```
class Child1 extends Base {
  // child members and overridden methods 
}
```

Similarly Child2 as -

```
class Child2 extends Base {
      // child members and overridden methods 
    }
```

I have some methods and variable in Base class which are used only in Child1.
 but what happened now.
Does Byte code of Child1 and Child2 contain Byte code of base class. If not than is there any issue extending child2 with Base class

Comment: I often think, why does this even matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It contains a reference to `Base`.  But why would there be any issue?

Comment: @LouisWasserman , So Child1 and Child2 does not contain byte code of Base class

Comment: That's what I said, yes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman , What about runtime, Does Running environment consider Child1 and Base class as a same class or two different class.

Comment: Different classes.  Why would it consider them the same?